# Calculating the euler angles of a line relative to three axes

Tags: math, geometry, angle, euler-angles

I have asked a question similar to this before but have since got further and also didn't tag the question right and wanted to get a bit of help on the maths around the question if possible.

I have a 3D sphere with points evenly spaced on its surface of which I know the coordinates. From these coordinates I am trying to define the orientation of some spikes that are coming out of the surface of my sphere along the vector between the centre of the sphere and the point at which the coordinates lie.

The idea is these euler angles will be very helpful in later aligning the spikes so they are all in roughly the same orientation if I am am to box out all of the spikes from an image.

Since the coordinates on the sphere are evenly spaced i can just take the average x, y and z coordinates to give me the centre and I can then draw a vector from the centre to each coordinate in turn.

The euler angles I need to calculate in this case are initially around the z axis, then around the new y axis, and finally again around the new z axis.

My centre point is currently being defined as the average coordinate of all my coordinates. This works as the coordinates are evenly spaced around the sphere.

I then use the equation that states

```
cos(theta) = dot product of the two vectors / magnitude of each vector multiplied together
```

on the x and y axis. One of my vectors is the x and y of the vector i am interested in whilst the other is the y axis (0,1). This tells me the rotation around the z axis with the y axis being 0. I also calculate the gradient of the line on this 2D plane to calculate whether I am working between 0 and +180 or 0 and -180.

I then rotate the x axis about the angle just calculated to give me x' using a simple 2D rotation matrix.

I then calculate the angle in the same way above but this time around the y axis using x' and z' as my second vector (where z' = z).

Finally I repeat the same as stated above to calculate the new z'' and x'' and do my final calculation.

This gives me three angles but when I display in matlab using the quiver3 command I do not get the correct orientations using this method. I believe I just do not understand how to calculate euler angles correctly and am messing something up along the way.

I was hoping someone more knowledgeable than me could take a glance over my planned method of euler angle calculation and spot any flaws.

Thanks.

Comment: *"The idea is these euler angles will be very helpful"* is rarely true, no matter what comes after. I didn't quite understand what you are trying to do. You have two (or possibly more) spiked spheres with cartesian spike coordinates and you want to align them, right? Then, how will Euler angles help you? And what would the Euler angles represent? Are they supposed to rotate a reference direction towards a spike? If so, you have one underspecified degree of freedom (the rotation about the spike direction can be arbitrary).

Comment: Sorry my explanation wasn't good enough. The idea is each euler angle would essentially align the 'spikes' to the z axis. The reason the euler angles would be useful is because the program I then use for averaging of the spikes uses euler angles to align each particle and then carries out the averaging step. The euler angles will simultaneously quicken the speed of alignment and ensure particles are less likely to be miss-aligned.

Comment: Wouldn't this question be better suited for math.stackexchange ?